# Call a parent component function from a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Fairly new to React. I have a lottery wheel as part of a hobby project website:
The Wheel object was downloaded with npm:

```
npm install lottery-wheel
```

```
import Wheel from 'lotter-wheel'
```

```
class Lottery extends Component {
   constructor() {
     bla bla 
   }
  
  componentDidMount() {
     new Wheel( {
        el: document.querySelector("#wheel"),
            onSuccess(data) {
              alert(`Congratulations, you picked up ${data.text}`)
              /* I want to pass the data here to Parent */ 
            },
            onButtonHover(anime, button) {
                anime({
                  targets: button,
                  scale: 1.3,
                  perspective: 80,
                  duration: 400
                });
            },
     });
  }

  render() {
  
    return (
      <div id="wheel"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

SO, In the callback-function 'onSuccess' I want to pass the 'data' from the Wheel child component to the 'Lottery' parent component.

How can I do this? I know how props work but not in this case.. Can I use a hook, in that case, how?
I want avoid downloading and going into 'Wheel' definition since it was not created by me.

Comment: What is `Wheel`? Where is child component `Lottery` is rendering? `componentDidMount` isn't for rendering anything, that is what the `render` function is for. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example.

Comment: Good point, updated :)

Comment: So, `Wheel` is not a react component. Fine. What are you trying to pass back to the parent, or rather, what callback is the parent passing to `Wheel` to be used as a callback?

Comment: Nothing at the moment, but I don't know how to implement this

Comment: you may try defining a function outside your componentDidMount, for example: `myCallBack = data => { alert(data); }` then call it from your `onSuccess(data) { this.myCallBack('Hi');}`... tell us what happens next.

Comment: Tried this. In that case I think that I'm in the scope of the 'Wheel' component and it can't find the function. I will test it again!

Comment: Ok, so in that case I'm getting "myCallback is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function and set as the `onSuccess` callback in the `Wheel`.

```
class Lottery extends Component {
  successHandler = data => {
    alert(`Congratulations, you picked up ${data.text}`);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    new Wheel({
      el: document.querySelector("#wheel"),
      data: [{
        text: 'apple',
        chance: 20
      }, {
        text: 'banana'
      }, {
        text: 'orange'
      }, {
        text: 'peach'
      }],
      onSuccess: this.successHandler,
      onButtonHover(anime, button) {
        anime({
          targets: button,
          scale: 1.3,
          perspective: 80,
          duration: 400
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div id="wheel"></div>;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit call-a-parent-component-function-from-a-child-component]

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple.. I was stuck in the thought of calling another function within the onSuccess. Thank you Drew <3